# Prove that $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:(y\neq 0)\vee (x>0)\}$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm working on a multivariable integration problem and, at some point, I need to use Poincaré Lemma. To justify that I verify the Lemma's hypothesis conditions, I need to prove that the set
$$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:(y\neq 0)\vee (x>0)\}$$
is connected. In fact, proving it's simply connected will work as well for my excercise, I don't know wich way is easier, and in any case how to prove it cannot be represented as the union of two or more disjoint non-empty open subsets. I will thank any help or advice.

Comment: It isn't. It can be written as $A=\mathbb{R_+^*}^2\cup (\mathbb{R_+^*}\times \mathbb{R_-^*})$, which is the union of two open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Bcpicao I'm sorry, I wrote it wrong. I used the symbol $\wedge$ instead of $\vee$. Now it's correct, check the edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof that the space $A$ is connected. In fact we'll show it's path-connected by explicitly exhibiting a continuous path from an arbitrary point to the point $(1,0)$. To exhibit a path between two arbitrary points in $A$, simply concatenate their paths to $(1,0)$.

Consider some $(x,y) \in A$. Let $\gamma(t) = ( (1-t)x + t, (1-t)y)$ be the straight line connecting $(x,y)$ and $(1,0)$.. To see that $\gamma(t)\in A$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, first observe that $\gamma(t) = (1,0)\in A$. Now consider the following cases:

(I) If $y > 0$, then $(1-t)y > 0$ so $\gamma(t) \in A$ for all $t\in [0,1[.$

(II) If $y < 0$, then certainly $(1-t)y < 0$ for all $t\in [0,1[$.

(III) If $y = 0$ and $x > 0$, then $(1-t)y = 0$ and $(1-t)x + t > (1-t)x > 0$ for all $t\in[0,1[$.

In all cases $\gamma(t)\in A$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Thus we have shown that any point in $A$ can be connected with $(1,0)$ by a straight line. (Such a space is called "[star-shaped.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain)")

Answer (score 1):

The space you presented is just $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{ (x,0) : x\leq0 \}$. That is you are removing from the real plane the half line starting at the origin and going through the negative part of the $x$ axis.

You can easily show it is path connected, thus it is connected.
It is also simply connected but from the phrasing of your questions I would think you are not entirely familiar with this concept, am I right?

Simply connected means that the first homotopy group of the space is trivial. If you do not know the definition of this group: this is equivalent to the fact that every loop in your space can be contracted to its basepoint.

Comment: I'n my class, a simply connected set it's defined as you said. For me, the easiest "graphical mental image" of it may be that one set is simpy connected if it "has no holes". My bad or weird phrasing may be due to the fact that english isn't my mother tongue, I'm sorry.